# Voltage fluctuations and GFCI tripping drivng me crazy

Tags: wiring

Voltage at a GFCI pug in the bathroom goes down 20 volts when I plug in a 1800 watt hair dryer from 120 to around 100.  At the same time when I measure the voltage at a plug in the kitchen it goes up 20 volts from 120 to 140.

The bathroom GFCI triggers randomly with nothing plugged into it.  The GFCI doesn't seem to trigger by loading or voltage fluctuations.

After checking the breakers and grounds an electrician told me it must be a Edison transformer issue and to call Edison which I did.  Edison found nothing wrong yet.

Help

Comment: I have you tried replacing the GFCI unit yet?

Comment: Age of wiring, location, would help.

Comment: This sounds like a bad or loose neutral. Check all the devices on the circuit, looking for bad/loose connections.

Answer (score 4):

A faulty shared neutral can do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing in my house, the upper floor of which was wired long after the house was constructed, and was an obvious case of "homeowner wiring". The upper floor was wired with an ungrounded "[Edison circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_neutral#Shared_neutral)": that is, two 120V hots and a shared neutral.

This is a really bad idea for a lot of reasons, but here are just two:

- Though the *voltage* on the shared neutral is always zero, the *current* through a system is constant. Which means that in theory you could end up with a situation where there was 15 amps on each hot and 30 on the neutral.  **The circuit breaker is on the hots, not the neutral**, so it will not trip for an overcurrent situation, even though the neutral might be getting dangerously warm.

If the circuit is wired in this way then it is wired incorrectly; in a correctly wired Edison circuit, the currents *subtract* rather than *add*. Every Edison circuit I've seen so far in a real house has been wired incorrectly. If you work out the sequence of events which led to this situation, often you find that the circuit *was* wired correctly when it was installed, and then a later modification caused it to become incorrect. Use caution when modifying existing circuits if you do not have a complete understanding of the whole system.

- A GFCI measures the difference in current between the hot and the neutral. I discovered that my upstairs was an Edison circuit when I installed a GFCI -- figuring that if I didn't have a safety ground at least I could have ground fault protection -- and it triggered at random.  Clearly the neutral carrying the current for both hots means that it is often going to be unequal to the current on one of the hots.

Commenter Tester101 below notes that this only happens if the circuit is miswired; again, in my house, the circuit was miswired. It might be in yours too.

Fortunately for me the Edison circuit in question was wired up after construction of the house and the conduit it was in was easily accessed. I replaced it with a proper pair of circuits, each of which had a dedicated neutral.

Good luck! These can be a real pain to deal with.

If you're going to be rewiring stuff in the kitchen and bathroom anyways I encourage you to bring the whole thing up to code: dedicated GFCI circuits in the bathroom and kitchens, at least two in the kitchen, and dedicated circuits for high-initial-current inductive loads like dishwasher, refrigerator, microwave, disposal, and so on.

Comment: If you're sharing a neutral (aka multiwire branch circuit), the neutral will only carry the unbalanced current. Meaning if you have 15 amperes on each hot, the neutral will have 0 amperes. If the hots are 10 and 12 amperes, the neutral will have 2 amperes.

Comment: @Tester101: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's assuming that the circuit was set up with the two hots "split phase". Given the idiocy of the homeowner wiring I've had to deal with thus far, I wouldn't be surprised if the two hots came from the same phase.

Comment: Maybe, but then the hots would come from separate single pole breakers, instead of a single double pole breaker. Breaker panels are designed so that alternating slots are on opposite legs. So if the breakers are next to each other, they're on different legs.  A multiwire branch circuit (or shared neutral circuit) is required to come from separate legs, so without seeing the wiring that's how I would assume it's wired.

Comment: @Tester101: Right, that's how it *should* be done, assuming you're going to do it at all, which I think is a bad idea. In taking apart my hundred-year-old house I have found many places where the previous owners made let us say questionable choices regarding the wiring. In my particular case the Edison circuit was originally run to a fuse box, not breakers. I don't know how you correctly wire a fuse box with an Edison circuit, but whomever upgraded it to a breaker box did not do so correctly either. Best to assume it is wrong until proven correct!

Comment: If the circuit was wired the way you describe, the OP wouldn't see what they are seeing. For the voltage to swing link that, the hots must be on separate legs. If they were on the same leg, you might see the voltage drop at both locations, but you wouldn't see them seesaw.

Comment: @EricLippert, Your thinking correctly, just have a term mix up. If the voltage is 0 by definition the current must be 0.

Comment: @SomeGuy: Well, clearly we disagree, but we can settle it with science. Run a black wire from a 120VAC breaker to a current meter, then to a 60W light bulb. Then run a white wire from the bulb to a second current meter and then from the current meter to the neutral bus. (Current meters must be installed in series.) Measure the current on the hot and neutral sides. Now remove the current meters and run wires from the white and black wire connections on the bulb to two volt meters, and then attach both volt meters to the safety ground.

Comment: @SomeGuy:  My prediction is that current will be nonzero -- about half an amp, AC -- on on both the hot and neutral sides, and voltage will be 120VAC on the hot side and 0VAC on the neutral side. And therefore there is current on the neutral without any voltage. **Do you agree or disagree with this prediction?** If you disagree, what is your prediction?  When you post your prediction, I will attempt the experiment and we will see who is right.

Comment: @EricLippert -- Even a *properly* wired MWBC will cause a single pole GFCI installed in it to trip!  Also, in your experiment, you'll measure a few VAC from neutral to ground due to voltage drops in the neutral wire.

Comment: @EricLippert - Your expermenet will give you the result you predict, it is a test of bonding. It does not show current without voltage.

Comment: @SomeGuy: Then I am confused, because it seems that we agree that a volt meter will show no voltage on the neutral wire. Yet you claim there is such a voltage, because there is a current. Can you describe an experiment that would  measure the AC voltage that you claim is on the neutral wire?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Good point; I was neglecting the fact that the neutral wire is a very low-resistance resistor.